# Read only file system after every reboot - centos

Tags: centos, hard-drive, filesystems

Some time ago I got disk full problem and after that everytime I reboot my centos server, the system loads with read only system files.

Running  `mount -o remount,rw /` will solve my problem.

But because system loads on read only file system, it creates a lot of problem.

For example, the `70-peresist-net-rules` is not auto created anymore.

The network will not start with errors:

```
device eth0 not present delaying initialization
```

and many more.

This is the `dmesg` output:

[image]

Can anyone help me with this? I just need network to move my files to another server but I think I must solve the disk problem first, or is there another way?

Comment: Do you have put a "ro" option in /etc/fstab ?

Comment: no even i set errors=continue

Comment: this is my fstab http://8pic.ir/images/r3g1kqqf57yekjvacs8e.jpg and line end with jqfmt=vfsv0   1       1

Comment: All the options are not defined in manual. Could you try with the "defaults" options to see ?

Comment: @user1772630, is your disk still full? If your root (/) partition is still full, then try to free some space first and see.

Comment: no its empty now ... i will test defaults option as well but i thing there is another MAJOR problem for system load in SYSTEM FILES READ ONLY -and every file going to it